# Замер времени выполнения куска кода delphi

Tags: delphi, время

Необходимо замерить время выполнения участка кода. При старте и в конце участка кода значения возвращаемые GetTickCount одинаковы. Т.е. получается, что код выполняется за 0мс. При использовании функций Now и MilliSecondsBetween время выполнения так же равно 0, чего быть не может. Как можно точно замерить время?

Comment: GetTickCount выдаёт время с точностью порядка 10 миллисекунд, так что, если замеряемое время сопоставимо, - смысла нет. Используйте QueryPerformanceCounter из первого ответа

Comment: 100 раз можно выполнить кусок кода, например и это время оценивать
если цель - сравнить 2 алгоритма, например - подойдёт

Answer (score 1):

В своё время делал замеры по этому примеру: [Как реализовать сверхточный таймер?](http://drkb3.narod.ru/491_2_2.htm)

Answer (score 0):

вообще в делфи есть прекрасный инструмент для этого дела называется профайлер.

покажите код как вы с **GetTickCount** получаете время 0 мс

Comment: StartTime := GetTickCount;

    BufferSize := FStartByte + FCount - BytePosition;
    if BufferSize > Length(Buffer) then
      BufferSize := Length(Buffer);

    if BufferSize <= 0 then
      Break;

    if InternetReadFile(hOpen, BufferPtr, BufferSize, BufferRead) then
    begin
      FBuffer.InsertBuffer(BufferPtr, BytePosition, BufferRead);
      BytePosition := BytePosition + BufferRead;
      inc(FBytesDownloaded);

      EndTime := GetTickCount;
      FDownloadSpeed := GetDownloadSpeed(EndTime, StartTime);
    end